# How can i append a text file to order the contents

Tags: python

I have a text file with about 2000 numbers, they are written to the file in a random order...how can i order them from within python? Any help is  appreciated

```
file = open('file.txt', 'w', newline='')
s = (f'{item["Num"]}')
file.write(s + '\n')
file.close()
read = open('file.txt', 'a')
sorted(read)
```

Comment: Please post a sample data from your text file along with the desired output.

Comment: What does the file `file.txt` contains ? How do you wanna sort it ? Please elaborate, while asking a question. It will only help you

Comment: Why can't you just overwrite the file?  Why are you writing the data in random order if you want them sorted?

Comment: @ScottHunter the data is pulled from a server - it just happens to be in that order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- read the contents of the file: open('file.txt', 'r').read().
- split the content using a separator: separator.split(contents)
- convert each item to a number, otherwise, you won't be able to sort numerically: int(item)
- sort the numbers: sorted(list_of_numbers)

Here is a code example, assuming the file is space separated and that the numbers are integers:

```
import re 
file_contents = open("file.txt", "r").read() # read the contents
separator = re.compile(r'\s+', re.MULTILINE) # create a regex separator
numbers = []
for i in separator.split(f): # use the separator
    try:
        numbers.append(int(i)) # convert to integers and append
    except ValueError: # if the item is not an integer, continue
        pass
 sorted_numbers = sorted(numbers)
```

You can now append the sorted content to another file:

```
with open("toappend.txt", "a") as appendable:
    appendable.write(" ".join(sorted_numbers)
```

Comment: thanks for the response...however i'm not too sure about `for i in separator.spli(f):` line, is that correct as `re.pattern` doesnt have spli as an attribute

Comment: Ooops, my fault! It should be separator.split. I fixed it now in the answer.